# Remove footnote marks from \listoftables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, captions, footnotes

I'm using footnote marks in my table captions like this:

`\caption{This is title\protect\footnotemark with a foot note}`

and then I just use a `\footnotetext{Closer explanation...}` .

This works just fine, but at the end of my document I want to refer to all my tables with `\listoftables`. The footmarks remain in titles in the list, but they have different numbers than those in the text - also there are no footnote texts on the page with the list.

Is there a way either to get rid of the footnote marks in the `\listoftables` *or* to get the footnote texts appear also on the page with the list?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Use the optional argument for `\caption`: `\caption[text with no footnotes]{text with footnote}`.

Comment: Better yet, don't footnote captions. The placement of the footnote will be unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, the optional argument works fine!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the optional argument for `\caption`:

```
\caption[text with no footnotes]{text with footnote\footnotemark}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,paperheight=12cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[text with no footnotes]{text with footnote\footnotemark}
\label{fig:test}
 \end{figure}
\footnotetext{test footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as **egreg** has pointed out in a comment, the best option is to try and avoid footnotes in captions for floating objects, since the footnote text and the floating object might result in different pages! This shows this phenomenon (footnote text on page 3, footnote mark on page 4!):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper,paperheight=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\chapter{Test}
some text
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption[text with no footnotes]{text with footnote\footnotemark}
\label{fig:test}
 \end{figure}
\footnotetext{test footnote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. thanks a ton!